# Text selection in chrome etc

Tags: javascript

```
function getPosition () {

    if ($.browser.msie)
    {
        var textPosition = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
    }
    else($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera || $.browser.safari) {
        var textPosition = window.getSelection();
    }
}



<div><textarea rows="3" cols="50" name="textarea1" id="textarea1" onChange="javascript:storeCursorPosition();" onClick="javascript:getPosition();" onKeyPress="javascript:getPosition();" onFocus="javascript:getPosition();"></textarea></div>

<input type="Button" onclick="javascript:if(textPosition.text == null){alert('No position selected')}else{alert('position selected')};">
```

I have the above code, which is not working in Chrome, Safari etc. I'm getting the "No position selected" alert all the time, except for IE. In IE I get the "position" alert..

Any idea why it's not working except for IE??

Comment: `textPosition` has no scope outside of the function.

Comment: There is no need to browser sniff! `if (window.getSelection) { } else {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textPosition` has no scope outside of the `getPosition()` function. Adding it as a variable of `window` should work, but isn't ideal:

```
var textPosition = null;

function getPosition () {

    if(!window.getSelection)
    {
        textPosition = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
    }
    else 
    {
        textPosition = window.getSelection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Aaahhh :) but still no working :( I'v created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/5qtLS/ and even if I write something in the textarea, in chrome it still alert me with no position selected.

When you click in the textarea and click the button it should remain position to textarea and alert with position selected.

Comment: Found an error in my own code, so now it works :) thx for helping out